Docker build for go-fitz and go-tesseract
I'm trying to use Docker to containerize a Go application that has go-fitz and go-tesseract as dependencies.
This is what I have so far:
FROM golang:alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies for go-fitz.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git gcc musl-dev

# Install dependencies for go-tesseract.
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    tesseract-ocr \
    tesseract-dev \
    leptonica-dev

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -tags musl -o main

CMD ["sh"]

I can build the image for either go-fitz or go-tesseract, but for some reason not both.
When I add the g++ dependency for go-tesseract, I see this error:
2.435 /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_arm64/link: running g++ failed: exit status 1
2.435 /usr/bin/g++ -o $WORK/b001/exe/a.out -Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=_cgo_panic -Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=_cgo_topofstack -Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=crosscall2 -Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib /tmp/go-link-818745495/go.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000000.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000001.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000002.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000003.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000004.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000005.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000006.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000007.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000008.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000009.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000010.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000011.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000012.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000013.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000014.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000015.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000016.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000017.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000018.o /tmp/go-link-818745495/000019.o -O2 -g -L/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz@v1.24.14/libs -lmupdf_linux_arm64_musl -lmupdfthird_linux_arm64_musl -lm -O2 -g -L/usr/local/lib -llept -ltesseract -llept -ltesseract -O2 -g -lpthread -no-pie
2.435 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -llept: No such file or directory
2.435 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -llept: No such file or directory
2.435 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I suspect that some wires are getting crossed between g++ and gcc for go-fitz, but I'm not sure because I'm not familiar with linking for c-go. I'm concerned that I'll have to build the Go binary with extlib static pkgconfig for go-fitz.
Any help would be appreciated!
I tried just building for go-fitz and just building for go-tesseract, each work separately but can't get it to work together!
